# How to fix Validation error in a JSON string with special chars

Tags: javascript, json

I have a following JSON string:

```
{
    "my_regex": "(?<somevalue>^(\S*\s*\S*)*$)"
}
```

When I try to validate the format using online tools like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/), I get following error:

> Error: Parse error on line 2:
>
> ..."object_condition": "(?^(\S*
>
> -----------------------^
>
> Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got >'undefined'

**So my question is, what should I do to make it a valid JSON?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`'s:

```
{
    "my_regex": "(?<somevalue>^(\\S*\\s*\\S*)*$)"
}
```

**jsonlint :**

[image]